# AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) in DLL causes EXE to not exit?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a project that consists of a DLL and a windows console application .exe.

The .exe calls the DLL. In the DLL I am creating a Dialog box.

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
MyDlg* dlg = new MyDlg;
dlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG1);
```

I had to add AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) so it knew to look in the DLL for the resources. However this seems to be causing a problem when control is returned to the EXE.

When I "return 0" in the main() function of the EXE the console window does not go away. I have to physically close it in order for the EXE to stop running. If I remove AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()) from the DLL (along with all references to MyDlg since they won't work without it) everything works fine when control is passed back to the EXE.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Connect a debugger and see what is preventing the process from exiting.

Comment: Fixed. My DLL is using DAO. I had to add AfxDaoTerm(); before exiting. Thank you.

Comment: Please post this as an answer so that others with the same problem will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. My DLL is using DAO. I had to add AfxDaoTerm(); before exiting. Thank you